# Wildfly 8.2 - Hibernate JTA Remove fails with Removing a detached instance (allready merged)

Tags: hibernate, persistence, jta

I am new with hibernate, I have build a project using a persistence.xml and the auto generated Entities and DAO classes.

In my test, it works the persist and the merge, but the remove is not working, it fails with the following error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance packagename.dto.Clientinformation#test1
```

I searched and thought that the problem was the object was not merged when removed, so I've added the merge before the remove, but the problem remains.

I guess maybe there is something wrong with my persistence setup.

this is the persistence.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" 
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="datageneralpersistenceunit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>packagename.dto.Clientinformation</class>


    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/Database" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="general"/>


        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:app/GeneralDatabaseEntityManager"/>

        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" />        
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />


        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="2" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="250" />


        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />  
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

The entity;

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    /**
     * Clientinformation generated by hbm2java
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "clientinformation")
    public class Clientinformation implements java.io.Serializable {

        private String responsibleusernameid;
        private String country;
        private String firstname;
        private String middlename;
        private String lastname;
        private String telephone;
        private String address;
        private String email;
        private String company;
        private String department;
        private String description;
        private Date creationdate;
        private String password;
        private Short discount;
        private Set<Tenants> tenantses = new HashSet<Tenants>(0);
        private Set<Payments> paymentses = new HashSet<Payments>(0);

        public Clientinformation() {
        }

        public Clientinformation(String responsibleusernameid, String country,
                String firstname, String lastname, String telephone,
                String address, String email, Date creationdate, String password) {
            this.responsibleusernameid = responsibleusernameid;
            this.country = country;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.telephone = telephone;
            this.address = address;
            this.email = email;
            this.creationdate = creationdate;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Clientinformation(String responsibleusernameid, String country,
                String firstname, String middlename, String lastname,
                String telephone, String address, String email, String company,
                String department, String description, Date creationdate,
                String password, Short discount, Set<Tenants> tenantses,
                Set<Payments> paymentses) {
            this.responsibleusernameid = responsibleusernameid;
            this.country = country;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.middlename = middlename;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.telephone = telephone;
            this.address = address;
            this.email = email;
            this.company = company;
            this.department = department;
            this.description = description;
            this.creationdate = creationdate;
            this.password = password;
            this.discount = discount;
            this.tenantses = tenantses;
            this.paymentses = paymentses;
        }

        @Id
        @Column(name = "responsibleusernameid", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
        public String getResponsibleusernameid() {
            return this.responsibleusernameid;
        }

        public void setResponsibleusernameid(String responsibleusernameid) {
            this.responsibleusernameid = responsibleusernameid;
        }

        @Column(name = "country", nullable = false, length = 100)
        public String getCountry() {
            return this.country;
        }
```

The DAO:

```
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

    import packagename.dto.Clientinformation;

    /**
     * Home object for domain model class Clientinformation.
     * @see packagename.dto.Clientinformation
     * @author Hibernate Tools
     */
    @Stateless
    public class ClientinformationHome {

        private static final Log log = LogFactory
                .getLog(ClientinformationHome.class);

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public void persist(Clientinformation transientInstance) {
            log.debug("persisting Clientinformation instance");
            try {
                entityManager.persist(transientInstance);

                log.debug("persist successful");
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                log.error("persist failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public void remove(Clientinformation persistentInstance) {
            log.debug("removing Clientinformation instance");
            try {
                entityManager.remove(persistentInstance);
                log.debug("remove successful");
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                log.error("remove failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public Clientinformation merge(Clientinformation detachedInstance) {
            log.debug("merging Clientinformation instance");
            try {
                Clientinformation result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
                log.debug("merge successful");
                return result;
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                log.error("merge failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }

        public Clientinformation findById(String id) {
            log.debug("getting Clientinformation instance with id: " + id);
            try {
                Clientinformation instance = entityManager.find(
                        Clientinformation.class, id);
                log.debug("get successful");
                return instance;
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                log.error("get failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the test that is failing:

```
    public void test() {


            try {

                Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                ClientinformationHome clientinformationHome = (ClientinformationHome) ctx.lookup("java:app/app-name/ClientinformationHome");

                Date now = new Date();



                log.debug("inserting new record");
                // Insert new record
                Clientinformation user1 = new Clientinformation();
                try {
                    user1.setResponsibleusernameid("test1");
                    user1.setFirstname("fnamr");
                    user1.setMiddlename("sname");
                    user1.setLastname("lname");
                    user1.setTelephone("+1111111111");
                    user1.setCountry("Spain");
                    user1.setAddress("Arven 2372 1, Madrid, spain");
                    user1.setEmail("test1@gt.com");
                    user1.setCompany("the company");
                    user1.setDepartment("Information Technologies");
                    user1.setDescription("This is de test user");
                    user1.setCreationdate(now);
                    user1.setPassword("test1111dd");
                    user1.setDiscount((short) 0);
                    clientinformationHome.persist(user1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.debug(e.getMessage());
                }


                log.debug("updating existing record");
                // Update existing record
                try {
                    log.debug("Get existing record");
                    Clientinformation user2 = clientinformationHome
                            .findById("test1");
                    log.debug("Setting middlename");
                    user2.setMiddlename("sname2");
                    clientinformationHome.merge(user2);

                    log.debug("Updated Client information");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.debug(e.getMessage());
                }



                log.debug("remove existing record");
                // remove existing record
                try {

                    log.debug("Searching client information to remove");
                    Clientinformation user5 = clientinformationHome
                            .findById("test1");
                    log.debug("Found client information to remove");
                    if (null != user5) {
                        log.debug("Removing client information with name " + user5.getFirstname());
                        user5 = clientinformationHome.merge(user5);
                        log.debug("Client information merged");                 
                        clientinformationHome.remove(user5);
                        log.debug("Client information removed");
                    } else {
                        log.debug("No records found");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.debug(e.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                log.debug(e.getMessage());
            } finally {

            }


        }
```

Can somebody please help me? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out, It was missing the @Stateless annotation in my test class... that did the trick, thanks anyway